# 301 Redirect from Dynamic to .html. Wants to 404 orginal

Tags: .htaccess

I apologize if in the wrong place. I have someone that has done 301 redirects where dynamic pages are being redirected to show .html. (www.printe-z.com/computer-checks to www.printe-z.com/computer-checks.html) They feels they should now use a custom 404 page for the original page(s); www.printe-z.com/computer-checks. What do you think? Leave it the way it is?

Answer (score 1):

301 is better for this scenario, specially for search engines: they will associate your old urls with the new ones so you'll keep your pages rank.

People accessing your old links will be benefited too since they will be automatically redirected to new urls.

Comment: Thank you Claudio. I was just making sure what I told her was right. She does not want to hear it. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

If the page has moved use 301. If it is removed all together, 404.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I told her. Your time is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

301 tells crawlers such as googlebot that the original page is `moved permanently` to the target page. So keep it as it is.

For your information, most URL rewritings are done using 301 Permanent Redirects. Also sending `domain.com` visitors to `www.domain.com` is an example where 301 redirection is used.

Comment: Thank you for your time Vishal. I actually do this stuff regularly. Problem is I am not the developer of the site in question and we have not been able to talk to them. They are using 301s where needed.They set up a custom 404 page for pages no longer on the server and it worked for the URLs tested. Type the bad URL and the 404 page came up showing the 404 page URL. Now, instead of showing the 404 URL it shows the bad page URL but with the custom 404 page body. Google seems to think there is no 404 error page set up for these URLs now. Any idea?

Comment: @AntonioGarcia: Best way to redirect users on custom 404 page if the requested resource (page) has not found is throught htaccess. Just add this to htaccess: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`. Now when you enter www.domain.com/some-wrrong-url then you will be shown that custom 404 page without chaning URL as what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

People might have bookmarked the old urls, or there may be a link on a website to the old url. Unless you are sure this is no longer the case, which you never can, you can remove the 301. But this is in a perfect world.

If the 301's are a maintenance burden, or have some other negative side-effect and the 301 have been there for some time ( >1 year), you could just remove them. But if not just leave them be.

Comment: You hit it on the head, thank you Gerben. I had the answer on my mind but needed confirmation from "professionals" that my advice to her was right.